# Elasticsearch multi_match query not working with synonyms and cross_fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch multi match query with `cross_fiels` type and synonyms is not working as expected.

I have the following configuration:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "my_mapping": {
                "properties": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "@version": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "field1": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "field2": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "my_synonym_filter": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "matthew,matt,matty",
                                "thomas,tom,thom,tommy"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_synonyms": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "my_synonym_filter"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following query:

```
{
    "query":{  
        "bool":{  
            "should":[  
               {  
                  "multi_match":{  
                     "fields":[  
                        "field1^8",
                        "field2^2"
                     ],
                     "query":"Matt And Tom Oldfield",
                     "type":"cross_fields",
                     "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
                  }
               }
            ]
        }
     }
 }
```

But when I execute the query it is not expanding the synonyms into every field, so if I analyze the query the explanation is as follows:

`(Synonym(field1:matt field1:matthew field1:matty) blended(terms:[field1:and^8.0, field2:and^2.0]) Synonym(field1:thom field1:thomas field1:tom field1:tommy) blended(terms:[field1:oldfield^8.0, field2:oldfield^2.0]))`

So if I have "Tom Oldfield" in field1 and "Matt Oldfield" in field2 the query doesn't match that result as you can see that it only expands the synonyms but for the first field (`field1`) and not the other.

If I remove the analyzer from the query then it will match a document with "Tom Oldfield" in field1 and "Matt Oldfield" in field2 and the query explanation is as follows:

`(blended(terms:[field1:matt^8.0, field2:matt^2.0]) blended(terms:[field1:and^8.0, field2:and^2.0]) blended(terms:[field1:tom^8.0, field2:tom^2.0]) blended(terms:[field1:oldfield^8.0, field2:oldfield^2.0]))`

Is there a way to make the synonyms expand to every field?

Comment: There is an issue in your configuration example - field1 is duplicated

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce your issue on my env with elastic 5.5.0.
Here is my [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) settings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "my_synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "matthew,matt,matty",
              "thomas,tom,thom,tommy"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_synonym_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_mapping": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following document was indexed:

```
{ "field1": "Tom Oldfield", "field2": "Matt Oldfield"}
```

On provided query ES creates the following [Lucene query](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html)

```
((field1:matt)^8.0 | (field1:matthew)^8.0 | (field1:matty)^8.0 | (field2:matt)^2.0 | (field2:matthew)^2.0 | (field2:matty)^2.0) 
((field1:and)^8.0 | (field2:and)^2.0) 
((field1:tom)^8.0 | (field1:thomas)^8.0 | (field1:thom)^8.0 | (field1:tommy)^8.0 | (field2:tom)^2.0 | (field2:thomas)^2.0 | (field2:thom)^2.0 | (field2:tommy)^2.0) 
((field1:oldfield)^8.0 | (field2:oldfield)^2.0))
```

where synonym is expanded for every field.

Comment: You are right. If I try it on ES on my laptop it works but if I try it on the AWS Elasticsearch service it produces what I entered before. Do you have any ideas why that may happen?

Comment: @SofiaBraun Could you please provide ES version?

Comment: I'm using ES 5.1

Comment: I tried it with ES 5.3 (the newest version provided by AWS) and it works fine. Thanks!